# What is this S icon on my android?

Tags: notification-icons

[image]

I have a S4 android, I have gone through the list of apps (both running and total) but nothing appears to match up. Can anyone please identify this icon?

Comment: It's a notification from an app, and it looks like a Samsung logo. I think you should find the corresponding notification on your notification panel.

Answer (score 1):

"Samsung account: A notification about your Samsung account has arrived."
Taken from http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/skp/faq/1046097